# solr search multiple category and tags

Tags: search, solr, schema

I'd like to use solr for the following scenario:

Each photo may have multiple sets.
Each set will have 1 "category" and 1 "tag set":

E.g. Photo A Set 1: "category" = one-piece (single item); 
       "tag set" = slim fit, vintage, red color (multiple items)

E.g. Photo A Set 2: "category" = sandals (single item);
       "tag set" = platform, red color (multiple items)

We want to be able to search the Photo based on the above category/tags: 
e.g. "platform sandals", "red one-piece", etc

Can anyone point us how we should set up the necessary schema.xml file?
(We don't need to show faceted category in our case)

(solr version 1.4.1)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You should add two fields to your schema. Both will be text fields. Your category is straightforward but for you will need to use a multi-valued field. See the following SO post - it is very relevant to what you are doing:

[What is the use of "multiValued" field type in Solr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800762/what-is-the-use-of-multivalued-field-type-in-solr)

```
<field name="category" stored="true" indexed="true" type="text_general" /> 
<field name="tags" stored="true" indexed="true" type="text_general" multiValued="true"/>
```

For your search you can either add search handlers to look at and boost specific fields or you can copy both fields to a third field and do a search on the combined value in this 3rd field. For example

```
<field name="text" stored="true" indexed="true" type="text_general" multiValued="true"/>    
<copyField dest="text" source="category"/>
<copyField dest="text" source="tags"/>
```

Comment: thx JP. in this setting, let's say Photo A has "red sandal", "brown dress", and Photo B has "brown sandal". If we want to search "brown sandal", can it avoid Photo A to be found (because Photo A does have "brown" and "sandal" in its tags, but it is not the correct match)?