# Document tagging

Tags: solr, search-engine, data-mining, carrot2

I have very huge solr index. I want to tag all documents with terms which better represent that document like [this](http://search.carrotsearch.com/carrot2-webapp/search?source=web&view=folders&skin=fancy-compact&query=rugby%20in%20london&results=100&algorithm=lingo3g&EToolsDocumentSource.country=ALL&EToolsDocumentSource.language=ALL&EToolsDocumentSource.safeSearch=false). Does this type of clustering results is also come under document tagging?

Which approach is better, Index time Document tagging or Query time document tagging like carrot2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Query time** has the obvious drawback that this makes the query more expensive.

However, the clustering results at query time are supposedly better, because at that time, more information has been seen and user feedback can be incorporated.

Note that technically, this is probably more **frequent pattern mining** than *cluster analysis*.

Maybe you should just try this variant of frequent pattern mining on your whole data set. You might not even need to store which documents were tagged which way - the solr engine should already be optimized to retrieve them again when needed.

Comment: Thanks Anony-Mousse, Just one more clarification. Do you want to say Document tagging (Either it is index time or query time) serves same purpose as that of document clustering?

Comment: Usually, tagging is a user-generated multi-categorization (look up folksonomy). True clustering is much more subtle, it serves the discovery of structure the human might miss; but that may or may not be useful to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I understood from your question that you want to know how to implement something similar to `carrot2` faceting using solr.

IMO you can add a **multivalued field** `tag` to your documents (see this [Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800762/what-is-the-use-of-multivalued-field-type-in-solr) for an example) with the cluster names for that doc, and then build **facets** using that field as explained in Solr wiki [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#Multi-Select_Faceting_and_LocalParams) and [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/StatsComponent).

Comment: Thanks Tony ,One question is , will that only retrieve single top terms from that fields, or Pharases will also come?