# How can I filter by tags in my search?

Tags: sql, solr, tags

I have no clue what I'm doing with SOLR so I have so far been able to get by doing simple things and I've been able to get by doing joins in SQL.

I have a table `buysellitems` which has a lot of fields in it like

```
+-----------+-------+-------------------+
| buysellid | price | buysellname       |
+-----------+-------+-------------------+
|      3558 |   140 | Multi Layer       |
|      3561 |   175 | form              |
|      3562 |   160 | Floral            |
|      3563 |   199 | Specks            |
|      3564 |   385 | Ruby Red          |
|      3565 |   160 | B&amp;W           |
|      3567 |   175 | Pattern           |
|      3569 |   125 | Fairy Floss Tunic |
|      3570 |   185 | Brandy Dress      |
|      3571 |    85 | Anissa            |
+-----------+-------+-------------------+
```

so I have something like

```
<entity name="item" id="BuySellID" query="SELECT 
  i.BuySellID, i.BuySellName, i.Price, ...">
    <field name="buysellid" column="buysellid" />
    <field name="BuySellName" column="BuySellName" />
    <field name="price" column="price" />
    ...
</entity>
```

So I have an easy time searching for items by name, I can filter by price, etc.
But users can also specify tags for their items in the `buysellitemfeatures` table which looks like this:

```
+-----------+-------------+--------------+
| buysellid | featurename | featurevalue |
+-----------+-------------+--------------+
|      3860 | color       | red          |
|      3860 | color       | white        |
|      3861 | tag         | leather      |
|      3861 | tag         | natural      |
|      3861 | color       | black        |
|      3861 | color       | pink         |
|      3862 | tag         | clothing     |
|      3862 | color       | black        |
|      3862 | color       | pink         |
|      3863 | color       | black        |
|      3863 | color       | pink         |
|      3872 | color       | black        |
|      3872 | color       | white        |
|      3873 | color       | black        |
|      3873 | color       | white        |
|      3874 | color       | black        |
|      3874 | color       | white        |
+-----------+-------------+--------------+
```

How can I filter the search results (which are items) to give items that have "leather" in the tags table even if it's not found in the name? Note that there are several columns for each item, and I'd like to also filter by color as well.

How should I import my data, and how would I query for things like:

1. Search for leather and display items that either have this tag or have it in its name
2. Search for the same thing, but filter by the color black (items can have several prominent colors as well)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your question appears to have much more to do with SQL than with Solr. I suspect that this question needs to be retagged.

Comment: I already have the necessary SQL to query for tags/colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep multi-valued fields for `color` and `tag` in your schema.xml. (See [What is the use of "multiValued" field type in Solr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800762/what-is-the-use-of-multivalued-field-type-in-solr)). Let's call these fields as `s_color` and `s_tag`. Also change the field name for `BuySellName` to `s_BuySellName`. (We will see why we keep the `s_` prefix in a moment.)

Then in your data-config.xml use sub-entities to get and index the values for these fields:

```
<entity name="item" 
        id="BuySellID" 
        query="SELECT i.BuySellID, i.BuySellName AS s_BuySellName, i.Price, ...">
  <entity name="color" query="SELECT featurevalue AS s_color FROM buysellitemfeatures WHERE featurename='color' AND buysellid='${item.BuySellID}'"/>
  <entity name="tag" query="SELECT featurevalue AS s_tag FROM buysellitemfeatures WHERE featurename='tag' AND buysellid='${item.BuySellID}'"/>
```

Now in your schema.xml, you can keep a catch-all text [copyField](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Copy_Fields) which stores the content of `s_BuySellName`, `s_color` and `s_tag` like:

```
<copyField source="s_*" dest="catchall"/>
```

If you search `catchall` like `q=catchall:brown leather bag` then it will search name, colors and tags.

Another nice option for you to consider would be [faceting](http://searchhub.org/2009/09/02/faceted-search-with-solr/). If a user searches for `bag` then you can show facets for `color` and `tag` to drill down.

Comment: I don't want to search for the colors, I want to filter by them. I want to search by the tags. I am also currently boosting the name of the item to be above other fields like description, so I don't want to merge them all into one field if possible. I could maybe merge the item name with the tags, but then I lose the ability to boost them by a different amount.

Answer (score 0):

I have also only recently begun to write SQL operations.  Like you, I've wondered how to filter out a large list of GUI options by tags so that a user would be presented only with options that were actually important to him.

Making the tags is easy, but not trivial.  You have to come up with an organization of tags that makes sense for your needs.

Filtering involves attaching tags to three entities:

- a target entity (say, a user)
- a source entity (say, a database record)
- a filtration criterion (criteria attached to a GUI control)

Conceptually, filtering is performed easily by performing an SQL INTERSECTION or UNION (or whichever set operation makes the best sense) on the two groups of tags.  When the target and the source have all the tags in common with the criteria, that should identify records to display.

BTW, you can attach tags to any records of any database at any time.  You can make a database table of tags, and then link any number of tags to the required database rows by using a many-to-many relationship via a bridge table between the database table and the tags table.

I think I'm on the right track.  Others are certain to be more authoritative than I am on this, but this is what I've come up with on my own so far.