# Storing Tags in SOLR

Tags: php, search, solr

I am new to SOLR and am looking to order search results by tags. **What is the best practice for storing tags in SOLR documents and what is the best practice for field type settings?**

Here is my current method where the tags are stored in a comma delimited list. The search was for "script" but this setup doesn't seem to produce accurate results:

```
[0] => Solarium\QueryType\Select\Result\Document Object
    (
        [fields:protected] => Array
            (
                [id] => 4912
                [description] => Neuarmy™ » YYY_NEUARMY_YES02
                [tags] => type,texture,script
                [save_date] => 1345825890
                [score] => 1.4771256
            )

    )

[1] => Solarium\QueryType\Select\Result\Document Object
    (
        [fields:protected] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1223
                [description] => Timbas Type & Logo Dept.
                [tags] => typography,logo,branding,script
                [save_date] => 1342703206
                [score] => 1.4771256
            )

    )

[2] => Solarium\QueryType\Select\Result\Document Object
    (
        [fields:protected] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1323
                [description] => ibg1pE.jpg 300×200 pixels
                [tags] => logo,script,interview magazine
                [save_date] => 1352914647
                [score] => 1.4771256
            )

    )
```

Comment: You can create a multivalued field for tags. Check [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800762/what-is-the-use-of-multivalued-field-type-in-solr][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800762/what-is-the-use-of-multivalued-field-type-in-solr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should choose a `multiValued` field of `string` type. The string field stores values without the pre-indexing mangulation and multiValued allows multiple values.

Then make php pass array( "typography", "logo", "branding", "script") for tags. Then Solr will recognise they are multiple values.

Answer (score 1):

Also refer to the following link for better understanding.
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Documents,+Fields,+and+Schema+Design